# How to get a colored packed itemize list in ConTeXt?

Tags: color, lists, context

Consider the following MWE:

```
\setupitemize[color=green,packed]

\starttext
        \startitemize
                \item Test one
                \item Test two
        \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

As you may see I use the option `color` to get green bullets and the option `packed` to reduce the space between items. But when used together, `packed` does not seem to work as the MWE will output

[image: itemize]

Why is it ignoring the `packed` options with `color` set and how to obtain the correct result?

Comment: Btw: Tested with ConTeXt from TL2018 and the latest beta.

Comment: You have to put the `keyword` and the `assignment` in separate argument, i.e. `\setupitemize[each][packed][color=green]`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Thanks. I forgot to look into `setup-en` to see where the color keyword should go. Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician You can *never* mix keyword and assignment options.  They *always* go in separate arguments.

Comment: @HenriMenke That may be, but up to now I rarely recognized that nature of arguments (be it because some commands only take assignment options or because they expect a name or reference instead of a keywords). It sounds quite logical though (now that I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your document is that you put an `assignment` and a `keyword` in the same argument for `\setupitemize` but ConTeXt expects both types in separate arguments.

The definition for the `\setupitemize` command shows that each type has its own argument.

[image]

Since both arguments are option ConTeXt uses the `\doifelseassignment` command to decide which type of argument you have when you use only one argument for the settings.

When the argument contains a `=` it is handled as assignment and `keywords` are just ignored.

```
\starttext

\doifelseassignment{color=green,packed}
  {Assignment list}
  {Keyword list}

\stoptext
```

Even though ConTeXt separates both argument types for all setups it is possible to mix and process both of them in the same argument with the help of the `\processassignlist` command this is never used and should be avoided.

```
\starttext

\define[1]\ShowKeyword
  {Keyword: #1\par}

\processassignlist[color=green,packed]\ShowKeyword

\define[2]\ShowAssignment
  {Key: #1, Value: #2\par}

\processassignmentlist[color=green,packed]\ShowAssignment

\stoptext
```

[image]